# How to launch jar files with GUI on second screen

Tags: java, swing

I have a jar file, which uses Java swing as it's GUI. My primary screen (on windows os) is a 4K display, and my secondary screen is a 720p screen. Is it possible to run the jar file on the second screen?

I have tried using

```
java -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false -jar JavaApplication.jar
```

But it doesn't work. Also, I have the code with me, so I tried running that on NetBeans on my secondary screen, but the run targets to primary screen.

Any idea on how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Use setLocation(int x, int y);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame c = new AppController("FilmDataBase"); 
    c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c.setLocation(1600, 400);
    c.setSize(600, 200);
    c.setVisible(true);
}
```

This code is in a class that extends of JFrame
[image]